# jquery:how to use ">" and children() in table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

**Html code:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>The first row</td> <td>The first row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The second row</td> <td>The second row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The third row</td> <td>The third row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The forth row</td> <td>The forth row</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>The first row</td> <td>The first row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The second row</td> <td>The second row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The third row</td> <td>The third row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The forth row</td> <td>The forth row</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$(function () {
    $("table:first tr").css("background", "#ffbbbb");   //work
    $("table:last>tr").css("background", "#ffbbbb");   //not work
    $("table:last").children("tr").css("background", "#ffbbbb");  //not work
});
```

**Result:** The background of the first table is changed, but the second table is not.
**Seems that the space selector worked, but the '>' and 'children()' selector doesn't, Why?**

**Working Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/6knk67gd/1/

I have checked the usage of these two selectors, but still can't find any problem in my code. Please tell me how to use them correctly, thank you~

Comment: you just missed the linked between the table and tr that is tbody so Arun P Johny is correct you can apply your css like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though we are not creating a `tbody`, by default the dom structure will create it, so all `tr` will a child of `tbody/thead/tfooter` not the `table` itself

Try

```
$("table:last > tbody > tr").css("background", "#ffbbbb");
```

Answer (score 1):

The sign > means direct descendant and there's a tbody automatically generated between table and tr. Try this:

```
$("table:last > tbody > tr").css("background", "#ffbbbb");
```